# How to Google drive api by sign-in with Azure AD

Tags: laravel, azure, google-drive-api

I'm new with azure. I want to know how to use google drive api by sign-in with Azure AD. I code all in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You cant if you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) which you should have already you will notice that the Google apis require that you authenticate with Googles Oauth2.

Google drive api for example allows a developer to access a users google drive account.  Google drive is owned by a company called Google.  Azure AD is owned by a company called Microsoft has no access to data owned by the company called Google.

Users will need to login to their **Google** Account using Oauth2 to grant your application access to their google drive account.